# FluentNHibernate tricky mapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate-mapping

When I load data everything is mapped and loaded correctly, but when I try to insert object graph with `Period`, `PaymentType` and `CalendarEntry` it throws an exception:

```
{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PaymentTypeId', table 'CashFlowCalculator.dbo.CalendarEntries'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

The reason is that there is no value for the foreign key column of the object that tries to insert. I can't where is the mistake in my mappings?

### Objects

```
public class Period
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual double OpeningCash { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CalendarEntry> CalendarEntries { get; set; }

    public Period()
    {
        CalendarEntries = new List<CalendarEntry>();
    }
}

public class PaymentType
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsIncome { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CalendarEntry> CalendarEntries { get; set; }

    public PaymentType()
    {
        CalendarEntries = new List<CalendarEntry>();
    }
}
public class CalendarEntry
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual double Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public virtual PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
    public virtual Period Period { get; set; }

    public CalendarEntry(){ }

    public virtual void AddPaymentType(PaymentType paymentType)
    {
        paymentType.CalendarEntries.Add(this);
        PaymentType = paymentType;
    }

    public virtual void AddPeriod(Period period)
    {
        period.CalendarEntries.Add(this);
        Period = period;
    }
}
```

### Mappings

```
public PeriodMap()
    {
        Table("Periods");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.OpeningCash);
        Map(x => x.StartDate);
        Map(x => x.EndDate);
        HasMany(x => x.CalendarEntries).LazyLoad().Inverse().Cascade.All();
    }

public PaymentTypeMap()
    {
        Table("PaymentTypes");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.StartDate);
        Map(x => x.EndDate);
        Map(x => x.IsIncome);
        HasMany(x => x.CalendarEntries).LazyLoad().Inverse().Cascade.All();
    }

public CalendarEntryMap()
    {
        Table("CalendarEntries");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Amount);
        Map(x => x.DueDate);
        References(x => x.PaymentType).Column("PaymentTypeId");
        References(x => x.Period).Column("PeriodId");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "nullable" PaymentType property of your on your CalendarEntry mapping, I think you have to specify it:

```
public CalendarEntryMap()
{
    Table("CalendarEntries");
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Amount);
    Map(x => x.DueDate);
    References(x => x.PaymentType).Column("PaymentTypeId").Nullable();
    References(x => x.Period).Column("PeriodId");
}
```

Instead, if you don't want it nullable, you have to manually set the PaymentType property of any CalendarEntry instance.

Comment: I made an object graph, and there is PaymentType that is not contained in the DB. I don't need nullable PaymentTypeId. I want NHibernate to store first the new PaymentType and automatically set PaymentTypeId to the CalendarEntry and after that to save also CalendarEntry

Comment: You code should be something like this: `
var paytype = new PaymentType(); var cal = new CalendarEntry(); /* fill your values*/ cal.PaymentType = paytype; paytype.CalendarEntries.Add(cal);
`
Then, due to mapping setting (cascade one), when you save the paymant type, calendar entries will be persied too.

Comment: See my answer below. I do it correct, but the result is now how I expect

Comment: The code you use to set the object graph seem to be correct: I don't understand if now it's working for you. If not, can you post how can you save the graph please?

Comment: I think you call something like `repository.Add(type);` right? The cascade setting will persist the CalendarEntry objects too.
But I'm worried about other stuff: I think somewhere in your code something is going to set to null the PaymentType property of the CalendarEntry object.

Comment: Not right. repository.Add(entity);Nowhere in my code null has been set. PaymentType is not null, only the PaymentTypeId foreign key is not set and this is the problem

Comment: Ok, but of what class is entity object? I think, for a test, you should only call repository.Add(instanceOfPaymentType); and let me know what happend.

Comment: I make it works. When I call repositoty Save from PaymentType repo it works. My mistake may be is that I call save from the CalendarEntry repo.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I use to set the object graph:

```
Period period = new Period
{
    OpeningCash = 2000,
    StartDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1),
    EndDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 1)
};

PaymentType type = new PaymentType
{
    Description = "Description",
    IsIncome = false,
    Name = "Name",
    StartDate = new DateTime(2010, 11, 23),
    EndDate = new DateTime(2012, 11, 23)
};

CalendarEntry entry = new CalendarEntry 
{
    Amount = 232,
    DueDate = new DateTime(2011, 7, 23)
};
entry.AddPeriod(period);
entry.AddPaymentType(type);
```